# sudo'd mysqldump over ssh syntax?

Tags: bash, ssh, mysql, sudo

I'd like a single command that:

- ssh's into my server as user foo, using the public keys I have set up
- executes a mysqldump of some database with the /etc/mysql/debian.cnf defaults-file
- to stdout, so I can pipe it locally
- while doing a sudo on the server remotely, because user foo is not allowed to read /etc/mysql/debian.cnf. foo is allowed to sudo bash but not sudo mysqldump.

This is the best I have come up:

`echo 'mysqldump --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf dbname' | ssh -t -i keys/id_rsa -l foo example.com sudo bash -s`

This ugly beast works, but produces: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`, and I really don't like the echo. There must be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh -i keys/id_rsa foo@example.com sudo bash -c "'mysqldump --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf dbname'"`

This will only work if sudo doesn't need to ask for a password.  If it does, you need the `-t` option to ssh.

Note the double and single quotes.  The outer quotes will get taken away by your local shell, and the whole `'mysqldump --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf dbname'` string will be passed to ssh as a single argument. Ssh will pass that to the remote sudo, so your remote will see the single quotes. The remote bash needs the single quotes to interpret the part after -c as a single argument.

Comment: Can you explain the quotes-inside-quotes? The outer ones presumably pass one string into the ssh, but what about the inner one?

Comment: (Added explanation to answer) The outer quotes will get taken away by your local shell, and the whole `'mysqldump --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf dbname'` string will be passed to ssh as a single argument.  Ssh will pass that to the remote sudo, so your remote will see the single quotes.  The remote bash needs the single quotes to interpret the part after `-c` as a single argument.